# deploy node js application on my server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn node js. I have a basic "hello world" running on localhost with this code :

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Now I'm trying to deploy it on a server I got from someone to fiddle around on with node.js installed on.

How do I get "hello world" to appear on my page: thomas.sitestatus.nl? I have checked multiple tutorials and I still haven't find a solution.

Comment: You make sure node.js is installed on your server, then you either edit the program to listen on other interfaces and on port 80 or you set whatever is listening on port 80 to proxy it. You possibly also look at wrapping the app in something that will run it on boot and restart it automatically. This is quite a broad subject though and not really suitable for SO.

Comment: Have you tried using `"0.0.0.0"` instead of `"127.0.0.1"`? I think using the loopback IP will cause Node only allow connections if the web browser is running on the exact same machine as the server, because that's the only time the server would be referred to by the loopback address; all other times (when the client and server are on different machines), the client would use an external IP to refer to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some basic steps you can follow to run your application on the server.

1) Copy your project to the server. Install npm modules if needed.

2) Then start the application on some port like 3000 (Later you can use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) to map it to port 80)

3) After that when you enter **thomas.sitestatus.nl:3000** in your browser, you will see "Hello World". If you configure nginx, entering **thomas.sitestatus.nl** will show "Hello World".

Feel free to ask if you have doubts or questions.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question but can I start the application from the terminal on my Mac? because I don't have access to the shell on the server

Comment: You can connect to the server using SSH from your terminal and then start the application on the server without any problem.